# How do I get the coefficients/interecept for each group/model so I can plot the fitted line for each group?

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn

I've written a custom class to group elements of a dataset, fit each group, and then run predictions for each group based on the fitted model.  I want to be able to return the coefficients of each fitting (presumably in a dictionary), so that I can refer back to them and plot the line of best fit for each.

Calling the standard `.coef_` or `.get_params` methods do not work because the items these methods attempt to retrieve are groupby objects.  Alternatively, I tried to introduce the following:

```
def get_coefs():
    coefs_dict = {}
    for name, values in dataframe.groupby(self.groupby_column):
        coefs_dict[name] = self.drugs_dict[name].coefs_ 
    return coefs_dict
```

But get the following:

```
<bound method GroupbyEstimator.get_coefs of GroupbyEstimator(groupby_column='ndc',
                 pipeline_factory=<function pipeline_factory at 0x0000018DAD207268>)>
```

Here's the class I've written:

```
from sklearn import base
import numpy as np 
import pandas as pd

class GroupbyEstimator(base.BaseEstimator, base.RegressorMixin):

    def __init__(self, groupby_column, pipeline_factory):
        self.groupby_column = groupby_column
        self.pipeline_factory = pipeline_factory


    def fit(self, dataframe, label):
        self.drugs_dict = {}
        self.label = label

        dataframe = pd.get_dummies(dataframe)

        for name, values in dataframe.groupby(self.groupby_column):
            y = values[label]
            X = values.drop(columns = [label, self.groupby_column], axis = 1)
            self.drugs_dict[name] = self.pipeline_factory().fit(X, y)
        return self  

    def get_coefs():
        self.coefs_dict = {}        
        self.coefs_dict[name] = self.drugs_dict[name].named_steps["lin_reg"].coef_
        return self.coefs_dict


    def predict(self, test_data):
        price_pred_list = []

        for idx, row in test_data.iterrows():
            name = row[self.groupby_column]
            regression_coefs = self.drugs_dict[name]
            row = pd.DataFrame(row).T
            X = row.drop(columns = [self.label, self.groupby_column], axis = 1).values.reshape(1, -1)  

            drug_price_pred = regression_coefs.predict(X)     
            price_pred_list.append([name, drug_price_pred])
        return price_pred_list
```

Expected result is a dictionary of the format:

```
{drug_a: [coefficient_1, coefficient_2,...coefficient_n],
 drug_b: [coefficient_1, coefficient_2,...coefficient_n],
 drug_c: [coefficient_1, coefficient_2,...coefficient_n]}
```

The pipeline factory is like this.  I'll be building this out with alternative regressors, pca, gridsearchcv, etc. at a later time (so long as I can get the parameters out of the groupby objects for the individual regressions.

```
def pipeline_factory():
    from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
    from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

    return Pipeline([
                     ('lin_reg', LinearRegression())
                    ])
```

**EDIT:** Added the get_coefs method as suggested.  Unfortunately, as displayed above, it is still returning the same error.

Comment: can you give little more details on how will a `pipeline_factory` look like?

Comment: @ParthasarathySubburaj: Yes, good question (apologies for the oversight).  It's simply a function that  creates and returns a pipeline object (see [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline.html)).  At the moment, there's only a `LinearRegression()` object in it, but it's there so I can build the pipeline further. I'll add it above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with `self.drugs_dict` which is a dictionary of `Pipeline` objects, so you can't use `coef_` on them directly. The `coef_` is anattribute associated with the estimator object which in your case is a `LinearRegression` object. So the correct way of accessing the coefficients will be `self.drugs_dict[name].named_steps["lin_reg"].coef_` instead of `self.drugs_dict[name].coefs_` in your `get_coefs()` method.

Comment: That makes sense.  However, I added the following as the last line to my `.fit()` method: `self.coefs_dict[name] = self.drugs_dict[name].named_steps["lin_reg"].coef_`, and then created a `get_coefs` method that just retuns the `self.coefs_dict`, but I get the same error as mentioned in my original question.

Comment: you should make the change that I mentioned in the `get_coefs` method.

Comment: Sorry, but I'm getting the same error :/.  I'm adding the method to the example code above for you to see.  What you're suggesting makes sense though...not sure why it's not working...

Comment: What is the error you are getting....can you provide me the full traceback error?

Comment: Ah, sorry...I wrote 'error' and I meant 'result/output'.  The output when I call the new `get_coefs()` method is: `<bound method GroupbyEstimator.get_coefs of GroupbyEstimator(groupby_column='ndc',
                 pipeline_factory=<function pipeline_factory at 0x0000023B12745840>)>`

Comment: This might sound lame but how are you calling your method? Is it by `get_coefs()` or `get_coefs`?

Comment: Not a bad question.  I was calling with 'lin_model.get_coefs'.  `lin_model` being the fitted model. When I call it with get_coefs(), I get a `TypeError: get_coefs() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given`

Comment: You forgot to add the `self` argument to the `get_coefs()` method.

Comment: We got it! You were right about `self` in your last comment.  However, I did have to move the creation of the coefs_dict back to the fit method (because its creation requires the local variable `name`.  While I probably could've left it in `get_coefs()`, I think that I may have needed to regroup and stuff...this seemed easier.  I'll accept your answer because it's fundamentally correct, but I'll post the correct code below.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

While @Parthasarathy Subburaj led me to the right answer, here's the completed code for anyone that may be looking for a similar solution:

```
from sklearn import base
import numpy as np 
import pandas as pd

class GroupbyEstimator(base.BaseEstimator, base.RegressorMixin):


    def __init__(self, groupby_column, pipeline_factory):
        # column is the value to group by; estimator_factory can be called to produce estimators
        self.groupby_column = groupby_column
        self.pipeline_factory = pipeline_factory


    def fit(self, dataframe, label):
        # Create an estimator and fit it with the portion in each group (create and fit a model per city
        self.drugs_dict = {}
        self.label = label
        self.coefs_dict = {} 

        dataframe = pd.get_dummies(dataframe)                                 #onehot encoder had problems with the data, so I'm getting the dummies with pandas here

        for name, values in dataframe.groupby(self.groupby_column):
            y = values[label]
            X = values.drop(columns = [label, self.groupby_column], axis = 1)
            self.drugs_dict[name] = self.pipeline_factory().fit(X, y)
            self.coefs_dict[name] = self.drugs_dict[name].named_steps["lin_reg"].coef_
        return self


    def get_coefs(self):       
        return self.coefs_dict


    def predict(self, test_data):
        price_pred_list = []

        for idx, row in test_data.iterrows():
            name = row[self.groupby_column]                                 #get drug name from drug column
            regression_coefs = self.drugs_dict[name]                        #get coefficients from fitting in drugs_dict
            row = pd.DataFrame(row).T
            X = row.drop(columns = [self.label, self.groupby_column], axis = 1).values.reshape(1, -1)            

            drug_price_pred = regression_coefs.predict(X)     #Use regression coefficients from dictionary (key = drug name) to predict
            price_pred_list.append([name, drug_price_pred])
        return price_pred_list
```

The TL;DR of the comments is that the dictionary holding model names and coefficients needs to be created under the fit method using sklearn's `.named_steps` on the desired portion of the pipeline, and then returned in a separate method (in this case get_coefs).